# How to search and replace strings that contain "=" characters in text file with Windows CMD (not powershell)

Tags: batch-file

I wrote this code based on some other examples but just can't get it to work?  (it's a .bat file)? The code writes the new file with all the old lines just won't edit the three  lines right with the "=" character. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

This is what the INTOUCH.INI file looks like to start:

```
[InTouch]  
AppMode=2  
AppName0=test  
AppName1=  
AppName2=  
AppName3=  
AppDesc0=New InTouch application  
AppDesc1=  
AppDesc2=  
AppDesc3=  
SAOConverted=1  
WinFullScreen=1  
WinLeft=-4  
WinTop=-4  
WinWidth=1032  
WinHeight=748  
UseNewSendKeys=1  
DebugScripts=0  
UseBigBitmap=1  
WindowViewerStartupIconic=0  
CloseOnTransfer=0
```

And this is what is written:

```
[InTouch]  
AppMode=2  
AppName0=test  
AppName1=  
AppName2=  
AppName3=  
AppDesc0=New InTouch application  
AppDesc1=  
AppDesc2=  
AppDesc3=  
SAOConverted=1  
1=WinFullScreen=0=1  
WinLeft=-4  
WinTop=-4  
1032=WinWidth=1000=1032  
748=WinHeight=700=748  
UseNewSendKeys=1  
DebugScripts=0  
UseBigBitmap=1  
WindowViewerStartupIconic=0  
CloseOnTransfer=0
```

This is my .bat file code:

```
Set "OldString1=WinFullScreen=1"
Set "NewString1=WinFullScreen=0"
Set "OldString2=WinWidth=1032"
Set "NewString2=WinWidth=1000"
Set "OldString3=WinHeight=748"
Set "NewString3=WinHeight=700"

@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
cd /d F:\
for %%x in (INTOUCH.INI) do call:process "%%~x"
goto:eof

:process 
set "outFile=%~n1_edited%~x1" 
(for /f "skip=2 delims=:" %%a in ('find /n /v "" "INTOUCH.INI"') do (
      set "ln=%%a"
      Setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
      set "ln=!ln:*]=!"
      if defined ln (
           set "ln=!ln:%OldString1%=%NewString1%!"
           set "ln=!ln:%OldString2%=%NewString2%!"
           set "ln=!ln:%OldString3%=%NewString3%!"
           )
      echo(!ln!
      endlocal
))>"%outFile%"
Exit /b
```

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to delimit the file based on the equals symbol and use two tokens.  Then you could do `IF "%%a"=="WinWidth" echo WinWidth=1000`

Comment: Why not write all lines not containing your three strings, using `Find` or `FindStr` with the `/V` option, and add your three known pairs to the bottom or top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the file's format to your advantage you can set the values of the new variables at the top of the script and then as you are reading the variable names from the settings file you can see if those variables are defined.  If they are defined then output the new value, otherwise output the original value.

The trick to this is the double variable expansion you get when you use the `CALL` and `ECHO` commands together.  First the for variable is expanded the name of the variable and then in the second phase of expansion the value of the variable is then expanded. That is the reason for the extra sets of percent symbols.

```
@echo off
Set "WinFullScreen=0"
Set "WinWidth=1000"
Set "WinHeight=700"

REM cd /d F:\

for %%F in (INTOUCH.INI) do set "outFile=%%~nF_edited%%~xF"

REM Read first line of file
set /p line1=<INTOUCH.INI
(echo %line1%
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ("INTOUCH.INI") do (
    if defined %%G (
        CALL echo %%G=%%%%G%%
    ) else (
        echo %%G=%%H
    )
))>"%outFile%"
Exit /b
```

Comment: I like this solution very well explaned and aplicable, How do I keep the first line "[InTouch]" from not getting an "=" character added to it? (The formatting of the question would not let me add it to the code block of the file to be edited.)

Comment: @knexmaster, I have edited your question.  I am not sure how difficult it could be to put a few spaces in front of a line so that is shows up as code.  Before I edit my code to account for it please verify that your question and input and output examples are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I put the spaces in and the box kept saying I had code formatted wrong and it would not let me post?  it is now correct.  There are several more lines to the file and all the same format. Your code works on all of the lines. Sorry about having to readdress but I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Code has been revised

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

Set "AppMode=x"
Set "WinFullScreen=0"
Set "WinWidth=1000"
Set "WinHeight=700"

for /f "skip=1 usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%G in ("a.INI") do call :proc "%%G" %%H

exit /b

:proc
set val=%2
for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%S in ("%~1") do set trimmed=%%S
call :getoverrideval %trimmed%
if "%override%" == "" (
  echo %~1=%2%
) else (
  echo %~1=%override%
)
goto :EOF

:getoverrideval
call set override=%%%1%%
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\w16coreeval>cmd /c a.bat
 AppMode=x
 AppName0=test
 AppName1=
 AppName2=
 AppName3=
 AppDesc0=New
 AppDesc1=
 AppDesc2=
 AppDesc3=
 SAOConverted=1
 WinFullScreen=0
 WinLeft=-4
 WinTop=-4
 WinWidth=1000
 WinHeight=700
 UseNewSendKeys=1
 DebugScripts=0
 UseBigBitmap=1
 WindowViewerStartupIconic=0
 CloseOnTransfer=0
```